# file.shortpath for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, vb6, converters

ho i'm converting a my project from vb6 to vb.net
Is there an analog method in vb.net of shortpath?

```
Dim DestinationFile As Scripting.File
...
DestinationFile.ShortPath
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you rely on this path? What about machines that have short names disabled?

Comment: Is that a line of code you can just omit since you are moving to .NET?

Answer (score 5):

No, modern languages are not built to use short paths, but you can use the GetShortPathName method from the kernel:

```
Declare Auto Function GetShortPathName Lib "kernel32.dll" _
(ByVal lpszLongPath As String, ByVal lpszShortPath As StringBuilder, _
ByVal cchBuffer As Integer) As Integer
```

Call using:

```
Dim name As String = "C:\Long Directory Name\Really really long filename.txt"

Dim sb As New StringBuilder(256)
GetShortPathName(name, sb, sb.capacity)

Dim shortName As String = sb.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

What I could find so far is that there is no managed code for this, but you can do this:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1

    Declare Unicode Function GetShortPathName Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetShortPathNameW" (ByVal longPath As String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal ShortPath As System.Text.StringBuilder, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> ByVal bufferSize As Integer) As Integer

    Sub Main()
        Dim filespec As String = "SomeLongName"

        Dim sbShortPath As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        GetShortPathName(filespec, sbShortPath, 255)

        Dim shortPath As String = sbShortPath.ToString
    End Sub

End Module
```

Method declaration was found at [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getshortpathname)

Answer (score 0):

Your VB6 is using the Windows [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) via COM.

It seems there's no functionality in .Net to get a short filename. Rather than using P/Invoke to call the Windows API, as in the other answers, it's simpler to use the same FileSystemObject through COM in your VB.Net. Just add a COM reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". Then the VB6 code will probably work almost unchanged in VB.Net.